# Edit the value of polygons depending on the presence of points in it

Tags: r, shapefile, vector, point-in-polygon

I have a shapefile (regions of France) and points (.CSV). Both are in WGS84 (EPSG:4326) and both overlap perfectly with the tmap package. I would like to color the regions according to the presence, or not, of points.

Very simply:

- presence of point, the value of the "POINTS" column of the corresponding region takes the value "YES"
- absence of point: "NO".

It's a fairly basic procedure on QGIS but I can't manage on R (I would like to implement it in a loop in order to change the points file).

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Add whatever code attempt you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a spatial predicate test, for example `st_contains`.

This tests if each feature of spatial object A contains each feature of spatial object B. If B were polygons, this would be true if an element of B is completely contains within A, but your B features are points, so this is equivalent to `st_intersects`.

Example using sample data (you should try and use real or sample data in your Q so we can test our answers):

```
library(sf)
example(st_read) # reads the `nc` data set
st_bbox(nc) # get bounds of `nc`
# generate 50 random points in the box
pts = st_as_sf(
  data.frame(
   x=runif(50,-84.3,-75.4),y=runif(50,33.8,36.6)),
   coords=1:2,crs=st_crs(nc))
plot(nc$geometry)
plot(pts$geometry, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Now I can run the test:

```
> contains.point
Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 100, where the
predicate was `contains'
first 10 elements:
 1: (empty)
 2: (empty)
 3: (empty)
 4: (empty)
 5: 15
 6: 35
 7: (empty)
 8: (empty)
 9: 7, 10
10: (empty)
```

The returned object is a list, because each of `nc` could have any number of points in it - you can see that polygon 9 has two, but lets check:

```
> plot(nc$geometry[9])
> plot(pts$geometry, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

OK, now we're confident we're doing this right.

If you want to add a column to the polygons if the polygon contains *any* point, then use `lengths` (not `length`) to get the length of each element of the list returned. Here's the first 10:

```
> lengths(contains.point)[1:10]
 [1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 2 0
```

and you can see the 2 in position 9. Good. If this is bigger than 0 then the polygon contains at least one point. Lets add the new column:

```
> nc$contains.point = lengths(contains.point) > 0
> plot(nc[,"contains.point"])
```

Which agrees with the first plot of points and polygons.

Wrap this up into a function for ease of use.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Spacedman it's perfect. I managed to get my script and loop to work thanks to this.

Thank you for your pedagogy it is very pleasant. Sorry for not indicating any code/tests from the start but other than providing "base" layers I couldn't have added anything. I've done too many tests for this to be interesting I think.
I will reuse the NC data set the next time without problem!